# Solving the expression $12x^2+x-16x^\frac{1}{2}=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, roots

The question: $12x^2+x-16x^\frac{1}{2}=0$

I've tried to do this by making $$x^\frac{1}{2}=a$$ $$x^2=a^4$$ $$x=a^2$$ and plugging the new values in my calculator but I still get the wrong answer. How would I do this sort of question?

edit: I was made aware that I put numbers before my $x$ values and have corrected that.

Comment: If $16x^\frac{1}{2}=a$, how are $12x^2=a^4$ and $x = a^2$?

Comment: If $a=16x^{1\over 2}$ then $a^2=256x$ and $a^4=65536x^2$.

Comment: Are you sure about the statement? Other than $x=0$, the solutions are not easy to express.

Comment: Following @lisyarus you end up with a depressed quartic, so you can use Ferrari's solution for a depressed quartic.  It's not pretty. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Special_cases_of_the_formula

Comment: This is a quartic equation in disguise which is not trivial to solve in general. It can be simplified to a cubic by factoring out $x^{1/2}$ but cubic equations are also not trivial to solve. This one isn't so bad, but the form of the solution is pretty nasty. You can find the solutions on Wikipedia for cubic and quartic equations.

Comment: You should just set $a=\sqrt x$, substitute,  factor out the $a=0$ solution, and you're left with a cubic equation.

Comment: @CameronWilliams. Does $\frac{1}{3} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}(144)\right)$ looks nasty ?

Comment: @CameronWilliams thank you I've managed to work it out and get the correct answer

Comment: @liyarus  I failed to realise that haha I've managed to work it out now so thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 2):

To solve the equation you should use the substitution $t=x^{\frac 12}$. The trivial solution is $x=0$. If you try to find other solutions, you'll get the cubic equation:
$$12t^3+t-16=0$$
Take the derivative of $f(t)=12t^3+t-16$, and you'll see that it is monotonically increasing. Hence the cubic has only one real root. This root does not seem to be exactly calculable (other than with tedious methods), as confirmed on WolframAlpha, but it lies between 1 and $\frac 32$.

Comment: why would it not be $-16t$ ?

Comment: desmos is showing $t\approx1.0754$

Comment: I am taking t common, and concentrating on the other factor

Comment: Sorry, I meant 1 and 3/2. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=\sqrt{x}$

Thus we get $ 12a^4+a^2-16a=0 $

$$ a(12a^3+a-16)=0 $$

Thus by zero factor theorem one value of $a$ would be $0$.

Other value:

$$ 12a^3+a-16=0 $$

Using [Newton Rapshone method](https://atozmath.com/example/CONM/Bisection.aspx?he=e&q=nr) you get one value of $x$ around $1.075$.

You will find that the other two solutions do not belong to $R$.

Thus the solutions of the equation are $0$ and $2$

Comment: Pls tell OP if you have any problem in understanding the solution

Answer (score 0):

let $x^\frac {1}{2} = a $

$ \implies 12a^4+a^2-16a=0$

One of the solutions is thus $a=0$. Beyond that,

$12a^3+a-16=0$

Be advised that there is only one real root left.

**Cardan's Method:** If the equation is$$x^3+qx+r=0$$

$$x=\left\{-\frac r2+\sqrt{\frac {r^2}4+\frac {q^3}{27}}\right\}^{\frac 13}+\left\{-\frac r2-\sqrt{\frac {r^2}4+\frac {q^3}{27}}\right\}^{\frac 13}$$
With the other two roots found with the cube roots of unity.

This yields a real value of around $1.08$.